# GRIDDB: Fix error on CentOS 7. "Job for gridstore.service failed because the control process exited with error code"

Tags: centos7, griddb

I am setting up a GRIDDB environment on CentOS 7. After completing the installation steps, when I tried to start the gridstore service using command    "systemctl start gridstore"    the command fails with the following error message.

Job for gridstore.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status gridstore.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I performed the following steps after the service failed to start.

`

```
Executed systemctl status gridstore command with it's output
```

```
gridstore.service - GridDB database server.
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-07-29 20:44:57 PKT; 20min ago
Process: 9025 ExecStart=/usr/griddb/bin/gridstore start (code=exited, status=5)

Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: Starting GridDB database server....
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: gridstore.service: control process exited, code=exited status=5
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: Failed to start GridDB database server..
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: Unit gridstore.service entered failed state.
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: gridstore.service failed.
```

```
Executed journalctl -xe command with output
```

```
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

-- Unit gridstore.service has begun starting up.
Jul 29 20:42:09 griddb gridstore\[8944\]: \[ FAILED \]
Jul 29 20:42:09 griddb systemd\[1\]: gridstore.service: control process exited, code=exited status=5
Jul 29 20:42:09 griddb systemd\[1\]: Failed to start GridDB database server..
-- Subject: Unit gridstore.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

-- Unit gridstore.service has failed.

-- The result is failed.
Jul 29 20:42:09 griddb systemd\[1\]: Unit gridstore.service entered failed state.
Jul 29 20:42:09 griddb systemd\[1\]: gridstore.service failed.
Jul 29 20:42:09 griddb polkitd\[701\]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:8938:10927 (system bus name :1.58, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul 29 20:43:02 griddb su\[8987\]: (to gsadm) root on pts/0
Jul 29 20:43:02 griddb su\[8987\]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user gsadm by root(uid=0)
Jul 29 20:44:54 griddb su\[8987\]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user gsadm
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb polkitd\[701\]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:9019:27726 (system bus name :1.60 \[/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback\], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale e
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: Starting GridDB database server....
-- Subject: Unit gridstore.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel


-- Unit gridstore.service has begun starting up.
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb gridstore\[9025\]: \[ FAILED \]
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: gridstore.service: control process exited, code=exited status=5
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: Failed to start GridDB database server..
-- Subject: Unit gridstore.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel


-- Unit gridstore.service has failed.


-- The result is failed.
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: Unit gridstore.service entered failed state.
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb systemd\[1\]: gridstore.service failed.
Jul 29 20:44:57 griddb polkitd\[701\]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:9019:27726 (system bus name :1.60, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul 29 20:50:01 griddb systemd\[1\]: Started Session 2 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-2.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel


-- Unit session-2.scope has finished starting up.


-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 29 20:50:01 griddb CROND\[9101\]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 29 20:55:47 griddb systemd\[1\]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel


-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
Jul 29 20:55:47 griddb systemd\[1\]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel


-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.


-- The start-up result is done.
```

I am looking forward a solution as I am stuck on this and cannot move forward with my work.

Anyone with a solution is welcome.